# The border radius on safari is different

Tags: css, safari

I have set border-radius property for button in my css file:

```
border-radius: 10px;
```

Everything is okay in chrome but on Safari it looks ugly.

Chrome: [image: Chrome] Safari [image: Safari]

Comment: Safari might have different ways of styling buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for my question! You should add only one line:
    -webkit-appearance: none;
That's it.
The appearance property is used to display an element using a platform-native styling based on the users' operating system's theme.

Comment: Nice !, I was thinking about it too

Answer (score 0):

Try " -webkit-border-radius: 10px "